# HTTPGET function call to intranet api on landing page is giving remote name could not be resolved

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs, landing-page, marketingcloudapi

I am using HTTPGET function call to my organization intranet api on landing page to get current logged in user details. When i am running the script on landing page it is giving remote name could not be resolved error. My MC tenant is S7 and have also asked my organization network team to whitelist the following IP address `136.147.128.1 - 136.147.128.254`.

After adding the IP on my organization network, i am still getting the error(remote name could not be resolved). Does anyone know what could be the possible reason. I ma getting below error.

```
An exception occurred when attempting to retrieve content by a HttpGet call. Error Code: HTTP_WB_RTV
 - from OMMCommon --> 

 --- inner exception 2---

System.Net.WebException: The remote name could not be resolved: 'intranet' - from System"
```

Answer (score 2):

MC can only access domains available on the public web. You would need to publish a public DNS entry to allow MC to find the service in question. In conjunction with a whitelist for IP addresses, this is still considered perfectly safe. For example, we have a intranet portal that we publish at a subdomain on our main website to access resources we expose so that outside connections will work (e.g. AD FS so we can SSO to Salesforce). You'll need a similar setup in order to make this happen.